# Parsing a string with double quotation in it

Tags: sql, double-quotes

I have a table in which one of the fields contains the string `302720"?`.

When I try to do a substring of that string, it returns an error. I understand that it is because of the double quotes within the string.

I tried replacing the quotation with `REGEXP_REPLACE`, even that didn't work.

Below is the SQL statement:

```
SELECT SUBSTR("302720"?", 0, 3)
```

Any comments regarding this would be appreciated.

Comment: so do you want to return the double quote in your result or do you always want to exclude it?

Comment: Which RDBMS (vendoer and version)?

Comment: What if you use single-quote instead of double-quote? `SELECT SUBSTRING('302720"?', 0, 3)`

Answer (score 1):

Please see below for an example.  You didn't list the DBMS, so I assumed SQL Server.

**Code**

```
CREATE TABLE SUBSTR_TEST(STRING VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO SUBSTR_TEST
VALUES('302720"?')

SELECT * FROM SUBSTR_TEST

SELECT SUBSTRING(REPLACE(STRING,'"',''),0,3) AS STRING FROM SUBSTR_TEST
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Sorry about that, I am using IPython notebook. DebugData field is a string which has 302720?". So when i take a substring of debugdata, it returns nothing.

 SELECT d.HardwareId, d.DebugReason, d.DebugData
  FROM 
 (SELECT 
    HardwareId, DebugReason, DebugData, 
    INTEGER(SUBSTR(DebugData,0,3)) AS d1, 
  FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE(Debug,TIMESTAMP('2016-05-16'),TIMESTAMP('2016-05-16'))
  WHERE DebugReason = 50013 and HardwareId = 550661626)

Comment: @user3447653 are you trying to do a substring in python? Or in the database? Which DB are you using (PostGRESQL, SQL Server, MySQL)?

Comment: My tables are in Google Big query. So using an IPython notebook, I query it.

Comment: what are you pulling it into, a list, a dataframe?  Please tag Google Big Query in your original post.

Comment: I am pulling it into a dataframe.

Comment: @user3447653 Ok, please post the python script.  I'd like to see the exact syntax of how you're sending the query to GBQ.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112443/discussion-between-pynoob-and-user3447653).

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this by hand, either use different quotes...

```
SELECT SUBSTR('302720"?', 0, 3)
```

Or you can escape the quote. You can do this by doubling the quote:

```
SELECT SUBSTR("302720""?", 0, 3)
```

Or you can use the traditional `\` escape character.

```
SELECT SUBSTR("302720\"?", 0, 3)
```

---

If you're doing this in a program, use a [prepared statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) with bind parameters. This avoids having to deal with escapes as well of avoiding a host of [security problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). The specifics differ by language, but it's usually something like this:

```
handle = connection.prepare("SELECT SUBSTR(?, ?, ?)");
handle.execute('302720"?', 0, 3)
result = handle.fetch
```

It's analogous to passing variables into a function.